# How to implement isDirectionalLockEnabled for SwiftUI ScrollView

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview

I have a scrollview that scrolls horizontally and vertically. I want to restrict scrolling in one direction at a time like `UIScrollView` allows with the `isDirectionalLockEnabled` property. SwiftUI `ScrollView` doesn't seem to have the property.

```
ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        ForEach(0..<5) { x in
            HStack {
                //scrollview content
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to set `UIScrollView.appearance().isDirectionalLockEnabled` in onAppear and onDisappear of scrollView.